# Is it Possible to Dynamically Configure XML Serialization?

Tags: .net, serialization, attributes

I have several classes that I serialize/deserialize, each with a number of properties, some of which I'd like dynamically use the "Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore" attribute on. The idea being if I want to save specific property info, I manage it by setting/clearing a flag. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by using the XmlAttributesOverrides class.  It lets you generate the attributes dynamically rather than specifying them in your source code.  The [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) for the class has a good example.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to dynamically enable/disable a .net attribute?

No. Attributes are baked at the assembly metadata at compile time. You will need to implement a custom serialization.

Can you simply imagine the consequences of being able to add/remove attributes at runtime? You could provoke disasters by removing for example the [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) attribute from the [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) class or setting the [ComVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) attribute to `false` on this same class :-)